# Is there a way to know all the provided shortcuts of a website?

Tags: accessibility

In order to choose what email address to use, i would like to know what shortcuts are proposed by an email provider. That brings me to my question

Is there a way to know all the provided shortcuts of a website?

I don't want to spend time looking  for cheatsheet. I don't want a site-specific or site-category specific solution.

solution that I am looking for:

1. a addon or
2. a small program that take the website name as paramter or
3. something I haven't think about...

UPDATE :

What I mean when I'm speaking of shortcut:

ctrl-B in outlook in order to boldface a selected sentence for instance

Comment: I would say this is one of those things your would just have to google each time for each new web app / software. I was trying to think of a way to do it programmatically but think that would be (almost) impossible as you would have to parse all the JS on the site and look for things that intercept key strokes, then work out if they were shortcuts and, if they are, what action they perform. If you do come across a plugin for this let me know, if not why not start one, I am sure a lot of people would love a plugin like that. Grab current domain -> find relevant markdown instructions -> display

Comment: What even *is* a shortcut of a website? Do yo mean URL shorteners such as bit.ly? And what is the relation between websites and email providers?

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen No  I am thinking of ctrl-B in outlook in order to boldface a selected sentence for instance